# Using Idiomatic Scala in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following expression,

```
val pageViews = spark.sql(
      s"""
         |SELECT
         |  proposal,
         |  MIN(timestamp) AS timestamp,
         |  MAX(page_view_after) AS page_view_after
         |FROM page_views
         |GROUP BY proposalId
         |""".stripMargin
    ).createOrReplaceTempView("page_views")
```

I want convert it into one that uses the Dataset API

```
val pageViews = pageViews.selectExpr("proposal", "MIN(timestamp) AS timestamp", "MAX(page_view_after) AS page_view_after").groupBy("proposal")
```

The problems is I can't call `createOrReplaceTempView` on this one - build fails.

My question is how do I convert the first one into the second one and create a TempView out of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of SQL expression al together by using Spark Sql's functions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

as below

```
pageViews
      .groupBy("proposal")
      .agg(max("timestamp").as("timestamp"),max("page_view_after").as("page_view_after"))
`
```

Comment: can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a dataframe available with name `pageViews` -

Use -

```scala
 pageViews
      .groupBy("proposal")
      .agg(expr("min(timestamp) AS timestamp"), expr("max(page_view_after) AS page_view_after"))
```

Comment: can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename